# how to remove time counter from notification?

Tags: android, timestamp, android-notifications

How to remove 'now' and the drop-down arrow from notification layout in my app. I am using a single layout for notification and yet it is expanding. I kept the height to 64dp and 50dp but no change in the size

```
    // Get the layouts to use in the custom notification
    RemoteViews notificationLayout = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_small);
    //RemoteViews notificationLayoutExpanded = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_large);
    notificationLayout.setTextViewText(R.id.otpText,otp);
    // Apply the layouts to the notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

[image: See this image of Android notifications]

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
...
       .setWhen(0)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) you can use:

```
setWhen(long when)
setShowWhen(boolean show);
```

By default `setShowWhen` is true, so you can set it to `setShowWhen(false)` to remove the timestamp.

Comment: what about the arrow??

Comment: What does the arrow do after removing the timestamp?